# How to format Dart code programmatically using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, command

We can format dart code using the command line tool `dart format .`:

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format

But can you format dart code programmatically using dart code?

Is there something like `DartFormater.format(str);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dart format` command line tool uses the [dart_style](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_style) package.

You can add the package as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  dart_style: ^2.2.4
```

You can use the formatter in your code like so:

```dart
import 'package:dart_style/dart_style.dart';

const String str = '''
void    main( )   {  
      print
      ('hello world!'
      );
   }
''';

void main() {
  print(DartFormatter().format(str));
}
```

This will print out the formatted string below:

```
void main() {
  print('hello world!');
}
```